# How to round to certain numbers

Tags: functions

What I want to do is be able to round all numbers below 0 to -1 and all other number to 1.
So that no matter what the input is it becomes either 1 or -1.

Comment: should an exact zero input yield 1?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I'm never rounding 0

Comment: "It doesn't matter, I'm never rounding 0" — Well, then you just want the `Sign` of the numbers, no?  I didn't suggest it because `Sign[0] == 0` in Mathematica.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
2 UnitStep[x] - 1
```

where `x` can be a number or any array of numbers.

---

If you never need to handle `0`, use [`Sign`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sign.html).

Answer (score 9):

Because the OP wrote "I'm never rounding 0", this will work fine:

```
Sign @ {-2, 0, 5}
```

> {-1, 0, 1}

---

Issue with `Sign[0] = 0`:

```
sign[x_] := If[x == 0, 1, Sign[x]]
```

or

```
sign[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sign[x], x != 0}, {1, x == 0}}]
```

then

```
sign /@ {-2, 0, 5} (* not Listable though *)
```

> {-1, 1, 1}

---

Usually **not** recommended:

```
Unprotect[Sign];
Sign[0] := 1
Protect[Sign];

Sign @ {-2, 0, 5}
```

> {-1, 1, 1}

Comment: (+1) But Sign is `Listable`... You can save a character!

Comment: `Sign[0]` gives the wrong result, tho...

Comment: Ah, I hate it when someone can't write what they mean. After all, "So that no matter what the input is it becomes either 1 or -1" is pretty darn clear.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
             MyRounding[x_] = If[x < 0, -1, 1];
```

Examples:

```
             MyRounding[5]
             MyRounding[-5]
```

give +1 and -1.  Note that this rounds zero to 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
x/Abs[x]
```

Conveniently doesn't work for $x=0$.